# C++: force the compiler to use one of two competing operators

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I've been playing with C++ recently, and I just stumbled upon an interesting precedence issue. I have one class with two operators: "cast to double" and "+". Like so:

```
class Weight {
  double value_;
 public:
  explicit Weight(double value) : value_(value) {}
  operator double() const { return value_; }
  Weight operator+(const Weight& other) { return Weight(value_ + other.value_); }
};
```

When I try to add two instances of this class...

```
class Weighted {
  Weight weight_;
 public:
  Weighted(const Weight& weight) : weight_(weight) {}
  virtual Weighted twice() const {
    Weight w = weight_ + weight_;
    return Weighted(w);
  }
};
```

...something unexpected happens: the compiler sees the "+" sign and casts the two `weight_`s to `double`. It then spits out a compilation error, because it can't implicitly cast the resulting double back to a `Weight` object, due to my `explicit` one-argument constructor.

The question: how can I tell the compiler to use my own `Weight::operator+` to add the two objects, and to ignore the cast operator for this expression? Preferably without calling `weight_.operator+(weight_)`, which defeats the purpose.

---

**Update**: Many thanks to chris for pointing out that the compiler is right not to use my class's `operator+` because that operator is not `const` and the objects that are being `+`ed are `const`.

I now know of three ways to fix the above in VS2012. Do see the accepted answer from chris for additional information.

1. Add the `explicit` qualifier to `Weight::operator double()`. This
   doesn't work in VS 2012 (no support), but it stands to reason that
   it's a good solution for compilers that do accept this approach (from the accepted answer).
2. Remove the `virtual` qualifier from method `Weighted::twice`, but don't ask me why this works in VS.
3. Add the `const` qualifier to method `Weight::operator+` (from the accepted answer).

Comment: You could make your conversion operator explicit.

Comment: OK, a good idea, and it's probably OK to explicitly cast to `double` when I need one anyway. Why don't you make this into an answer? Nonetheless, I am having some troubles marking the operator explicit (the compiler now cries "illegal storage class"). Let me look into this a little closer.

Comment: @MihaiDanila: `explicit` for conversion operators was added in C++11. Depending on the compiler/version you're using, it may not be supported at all, or you may have to give a flag to tell it to support C++11.

Comment: You're right. With VS 2012 express, it's not supported. Downloading 2013... Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365129/explicit-operator-bool-error

Comment: @chris: nonetheless, I thought the + operator would have a higher precedence than a cast operator, especially when one is not necessarily needed? So in line with that intuition, shouldn't the compiler prefer the specialized operator+ even without my massaging the cast operator? Especially since I have two `Foo`s as inputs and the result is assigned to another `Foo`.

Comment: @MihaiDanila, Turns out I missed the main point. let me update my answer.

Comment: first make your operator double and + both `const`.  Second, is not your `operator+` as written illegal?  It returns a `double` when the `double` to `Foo` conversion is explicit.

Comment: `operator double()` is already `const` in my IDE, thank you for the hint. The other one was not. Making it `const` seems to solve my original issue. How is that possible?

Comment: I've updated the snippet. Now it's exactly like in my IDE, minus the name of the class. This is the code that exhibits the issue. It seems to be due to the `operator+` not being marked `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version:

First of all, the `virtual` should have nothing to do with it. I'll bet that's a problem with MSVC, especially considering there's no difference on Clang. Anyway, your `twice` function is marked `const`. This means that members will be `const Weight` instead of `Weight`. This is a problem for `operator+` because it only accepts a non-const `this`. Therefore, the only way the compiler can go is to convert them to `double` and add those.

Another problem is that adding `explicit` causes it to compile. In fact, this should *remove* the compiler's last resort of converting to `double`. This is indeed what happens on Clang:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Weight' and 'const Weight')
>       Weight w = weight_ + weight_;
>   note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Weight', but method is not marked const

Finally, making `operator+` `const` (or a free function) is the correct solution. When you do this, you might think you'll add back this route and thus have another error from ambiguity between this and the `double` route, but `Weight` to `const Weight &` is a standard conversion, whereas `Weight` to `double` is a user-defined conversion, so the standard one is used and everything works.

---

As of the updated code in the question, this is fine. The reason it won't compile is the fault of MSVC. For reference, it [does compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac9fd187279295d) on Clang. It also compiles on MSVC12 and the 2013 CTP.

---

You may be storing the result in a `Foo`, but there is still an implicit conversion from `double` to `Foo` needed. You should return `Foo(value_ + other.value_)` in your addition operator so that the conversion is explicit. I recommend making the operator a free function as well because free operators are (almost) always at least as good as members. While I'm at it, a constructor initializer list would be a welcome change, too.

In addition, from C++11 onward, a generally preferred choice is to make your conversion operator explicit:

```
explicit operator double() const {return value_;}
```

Also note the `const` added in because no state is being changed.

Comment: Nice, and `operator+` can also be made `const`.

Comment: Chris, you are right about the return, but it seems the solution is to make `operator+` `const`. That alone removes my compilation error, without making the cast operator `explicit`.

Comment: @MihaiDanila, Not in Clang it doesn't. I'm willing to bet it's another small problem with MSVC.

Comment: Understood. I can't verify the `explicit` piece, but it sounds reasonable. So I will mark your answer as accepted answer. I would appreciate it if you put a footnote in it about how I solved it in MSVC, so that others who use MSVC 12 might benefit from it.

Comment: @MihaiDanila, I was about to :)

Comment: Also, the error you mention in the answer, while it was a real error in my snippet, is not the source of the compilation error. It's not even in my snippet anymore, so you might want to adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. If I may add, my error goes away in MSVC 12 if I just add `const` to `operator+`.

Comment: @MihaiDanila, I don't see how you could get an error in the first place with MSVC12 (which is the compiler in VS2013). I had a completely successful build.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42281/discussion-between-mihai-danila-and-chris)

Comment: Excellent explanation; this clarifies why `const` on `operator+` fixes the issue. It doesn't explain why removing `virtual` also fixes the issue, but makes a bug more understandable if MSVC somehow gets confused about the qualifiers in the absence of `virtual`. I just wish the compiler were smart enough to tell me about this ("couldn't use the more specific operator+ because of this and that").

Comment: one more question after rereading your answer: I thought that marking a method like `twice` const only implied that I couldn't write to its instance. From your answer, it seems that the `const` method treats all the instance members as `const` all throughout. Probably to protect the state of the members themselves from accidental writing, which makes perfect sense now. Is this why `weight_` is treated as `const`?

Comment: @MihaiDanila, That's really better as a separate question or research on `const`.